# Obter valor do XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Estou com dificuldades em obter o valor `true` deste XML:

```
<boolean xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">true</boolean>
```

tentei desta forma mas não o consegui:

```
var ns = xDoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            string strin = xDoc.Descendants(ns + "boolean").ToString();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Experimente isto:

```
var nodeName = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/") + "boolean";
string value = xDoc.Descendants(nodeName).First().Value;
```

O que isto faz:

Primeiro criamos um nome do nó, com o namespace e o nome indicado. O `GetDefaultNamespace` só funciona se o nó root tiver um `xmlns` de `http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/`. Quando o `boolean` for o root, então o `GetDefaultNamespace` funciona:

```
var nodeName = xDoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace() + "boolean";
string value = xDoc.Descendants(nodeName).First().Value;
```

O `Descendants` ([MSDN em inglês](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) devolve um `IEnumerable<XElement>` e não um elemento simples. Isto porque podem haver vários nós num documento XML com o mesmo nome.
Para converter o `IEnumerable` num `XElement`, usamos os métodos `First`, `Single` ou `FirstOrDefault`:

- `First` ([MSDN em inglês](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)): Devolve o primeiro elemento encontrado com o nome indicado. Excepção se não houver nenhum.
- `FirstOrDefault` ([MSDN em inglê](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)s): Devolve o primeiro elemento encontrado com o nome indicado. Devolve `null` se não houver nenhum.
- `Single` ([MSDN em inglês](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)): Devolve o único elemento encontrado com o nome indicado. Excepção se não houver nenhum ou se houver mais do que um elemento.

Por fim, tendo o nó, usamos o Value ([MSDN em inglês](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) para obter o conteúdo textual do nó.